# Aligning the vertical gap of cells in tabular environment

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{File Menu}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\textbf{Menu Icon} & \textbf{Operation} \\ [0.5 ex]
\hline 
\hline \\
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Icons/3x/add_new_solution.png} & 
\textbf{Add new Solution/Model} \\
\hline \\
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Icons/3x/open_solution.png} & \textbf{Open Solution} \\
\hline \\
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Icons/3x/save.png} & \textbf{Save} \\
\hline \\
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Icons/3x/export.png} & \textbf{Export} \\
\hline \\
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Icons/3x/print.png} & \textbf{Print Model} \\
\hline \\
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Icons/3x/e_mail.png} & \textbf{E-mail Model} \\  [1 ex]
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{table}
```

[image]

Can you help me about lowering the vertical distances in rows.

Comment: Please add a fully compilable MWE and replace your images with `example-image`.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit please .

Comment: It looks like the icons have some blank margin on top of them. Do you know they real vertical size?

Comment: they are 76x76  I checked them on paint there is no gap above them

Comment: @safag96 what I meant is to first make your code compilable and then, replace your custom figures with the TeX's example images. Therby, rendering it compilable in any PC.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
\newcommand\Cincludegraphics[2][]{%
  \addstackgap[3pt]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand\growby[2][X]{\addstackgap[#2]{\vphantom{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{File Menu}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\growby{5pt}\textbf{Menu Icon} & \textbf{Operation} \\ 
\hline 
\hline 
\Cincludegraphics[scale=0.07]{example-image} & 
\textbf{Add new Solution/Model} \\
\hline 
\Cincludegraphics[scale=0.07]{example-image-a} & \textbf{Open Solution} \\
\hline 
\Cincludegraphics[scale=0.07]{example-image-b} & \textbf{Save} \\
\hline 
\Cincludegraphics[scale=0.07]{example-image-c} & \textbf{Export} \\
\hline 
\Cincludegraphics[scale=0.07]{example-image} & \textbf{Print Model} \\
\hline 
\Cincludegraphics[scale=0.07]{example-image-a} & \textbf{E-mail Model} \\  [1 ex]
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different possible solution using the `valign=c` option added by the `adjustbox` package in combination with the `cellspace` package for some vertical white space around the images. I have also replaced the `center` environment by the `\centering` command as the former adds additional vertical white space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\cellspacetoplimit=4pt
\cellspacebottomlimit=4pt

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{File Menu}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{SlSl}
    \hline
    \textbf{Menu Icon} & \textbf{Operation} \\ 
    \hline 
    \hline 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.07,valign=c]{example-image} & 
    \textbf{Add new Solution/Model} \\
    \hline 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.07,valign=c]{example-image} & \textbf{Open Solution} \\
    \hline 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.07,valign=c]{example-image} & \textbf{Save} \\
    \hline 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.07,valign=c]{example-image} & \textbf{Export} \\
    \hline 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.07,valign=c]{example-image} & \textbf{Print Model} \\
    \hline 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.07,valign=c]{example-image} & \textbf{E-mail Model} \\  [1 ex]
    \hline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]