# Centering text vertically in table

Tags: tables, alignment, vertical

as the title states, I've had trouble centering text vertically in a LaTeX table. Something that should be really simple; I can do it with only click in Word, and every answer I've found online is either extremely complicated, or doesn't work for me.

A lot of the questions are very very specific, but I've tried my best to simplify the question as much as possible.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For example picture

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} \\ \hline
        a & \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{example-image-a} & b \\ \hline
        c & \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth]{example-image-b} & d \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This prints a table like this:

[image]

I'd like the text in column 1 and 3 to be centered vertically - ideally also the picture (which borders the top of the cell), but I can do without it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here are some related questions: [How can I align the pictures properly inside table cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531755/134144), [Managing text within table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507108/134144) and [Aligning the vertical gap of cells in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479595/134144)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of `cellspace` for the spacing above and below the image and `valign=c` from the `adjustbox` package to vertically center the contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For example picture
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|0c|0c|0c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} \\ \hline
        a & \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-a} & b \\ \hline
        c & \includegraphics[width=0.15\linewidth, valign=c]{example-image-b} & d \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I wanted! However, I ended up with an error (see link), do you know exactly where I should use \tabulinesep ? [link](https://i.imgur.com/KIBe7Kd.png)

Comment: Do you use the tabu package in your actual document? If so, please be warned that this package is currently unmaintained and can cause some undesired outputs/side effects. I therefore encourage you to not continue using this package. As far as I know most, if not all, features of this package can also be achieved with other, maintained and more compatible packages as well.

Comment: I do, sorry, I missed that. I've removed that package, I wasn't actually using it anymore. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks again for your help!