# Control placement of text in tabular environment

Tags: tables

[image: Text is not placed correctly w.r.t. each row]

Here is the code for the following rendering

```
\headerbox{Experimental Results}{name=results,span=2,column=1,above=future}{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Inference on IR images using WaSR} 
%\begin{table}[t]
\label{wasr_as_is_ir}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\dp\strutbox} % the devious trick!
    \begin{tabular}{@{} t @{\quad} ccc @{}}
         {\parbox{20mm}{\raggedright Original IR images}} &
         \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  & 
         \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  &
         \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  \\
        {\parbox{20mm}{\raggedright Direct inference}} &
         \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
         \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
         \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
        {\parbox{20mm}{\raggedright Retrained with gray scale images}} &
        \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
        \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
         \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
        {\parbox{20mm}{\raggedright Retrained with IR images}} &
        \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
         \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
          \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
    \end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{minipage}
}
```

I tried with different size of parbox but it did not place the text correctly.

Update:: I failed to explain that I am creating A0 poster and creating a header box in it. So I cannot use table (float) environment in it. After incorporating js' suggestion, I am close but text is still an issue. See latest code below and the new result.

```
\begin{posterbox}[name=results,span=2,column=1,below=setup,above=future]{Results}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Inference on IR images using WaSR} 
\label{wasr_as_is_ir}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} p{1.1cm} @{\quad} ccc @{}}
{\multirow{-8}{*}{\makecell[l]{ Original \\IR images}}} &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  & 
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  \\
    {\multirow{-8}{*}{\makecell[l]{Direct \\inference}}} &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
    {\multirow{-8}{*}{\makecell[l]{Retrained \\with \\gray scale}}} &
    \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
    \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
    {\multirow{-8}{*}{\makecell[l]{Retrained \\with \\IR images}}} &
    \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
      \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
    \end{tabular}

%\end{table}
\end{minipage}
\end{posterbox}
```

The text is too close to the image cell. I do not know why! Any help in getting the text a little toward left will be much appreciated.

[image]

Update2:: Answer to @egreg. I am using minipage but the text is almost touching with the image. Here is my code -

\documentclass[a0paper,portrait,showframe]{baposter}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}% for customizing the lists

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl,booktabs}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,ragged2e}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp} % trademark symbol
\usepackage{caption}

%%% Global Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{{figures/}}   % Root directory of the pictures
\tracingstats=2         % Enabled LaTeX logging with conditionals
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Save space in lists. Use this after the opening of the list
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Document Start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\typeout{Poster rendering started}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}
%%% General Poster Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% Eye Catcher, Title, Authors and University Images %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{poster} %
{
% Poster Options
% Show grid to help with alignment
%grid=true,
% Column spacing
colspacing=1em,
% Color style
bgColorOne=white,
bgColorTwo=white,
borderColor=lightblue,
headerColorOne=black,
headerColorTwo=lightblue,
headerFontColor=white,
boxColorOne=white,
boxColorTwo=lightblue,
% Format of textbox
textborder=roundedleft,
% Format of text header
%eyecatcher=false,
headerborder=closed,
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % a0 poster
%  textfont=\sc, An example of changing the text font
headershape=roundedright,
headershade=shadelr,
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, %Sans Serif
textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, %a0 poster
boxshade=plain,
%  background=shade-tb,
background=plain,
linewidth=2pt
}
% Eye Catcher
{ }

\begin{posterbox}[name=results,span=2,column=1,below=setup,above=bottom]{Results}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Inference on IR images using WaSR}
\label{wasr_as_is_ir}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{1.1cm} @{\quad} ccc @{}}
{\multirow{-9}{*}{\makecell[l]{ Original \IR images}}} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  \ \
{\multirow{-9}{*}{\makecell[l]{Direct \inference}}} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \ \
{\multirow{-9}{*}{\makecell[l]{Retrained \with \gray scale}}} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \ \
{\multirow{-9}{*}{\makecell[l]{Retrained \with \IR images}}} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \ \
\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}
\captionof{table}{Quantitative results}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
Precision & 0.4583 \ \hline
Recall & 0.9167 \ \hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{minipage}
\end{posterbox}

Comment: with package `multirow` for centering and package `makecell` for breaking the text

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550474/134144

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
  \begin{tabular}{@{} p{2cm} @{\quad} ccc @{}}
     {\multirow{-9}{*}{\makecell[l]{ Original \\IR images}}} &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  & 
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/input/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color.png}  \\
    {\multirow{-9}{*}{\makecell[l]{Direct \\inference}}} &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_as_is/ir/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
    {\multirow{-9}{*}{\makecell[l]{Retrained \\with \\gray scale}}} &
    \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
    \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_mastr_rgb2gray_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
    {\multirow{-9}{*}{\makecell[l]{Retrained \\with \\IR images}}} &
    \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603212920.750480_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} & 
     \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391732.530753_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} &
      \includegraphics[width=40mm]{images/wasr_with_our_ir_retrain/1603391799.096494_color_grayscale_resized_color_output_mask.png} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}
\caption{Inference on IR images using WaSR}
\newcommand\rowlabel[1]{\parbox{.2\linewidth}{\raggedright #1}\hfill}
\newcommand\IRimage[1]{\includegraphics[valign=c,width=.24\linewidth]{#1}}
\hrulefill\bigskip\par
\rowlabel{Original IR images}  
\IRimage{example-image-a} \hfill  
\IRimage{example-image-b} \hfill  
\IRimage{example-image-c} \medskip\par
\rowlabel{Direct Interference}
\IRimage{example-image-a} \hfill  
\IRimage{example-image-b} \hfill  
\IRimage{example-image-c} \medskip\par
\rowlabel{Retrained with gray scale images}  
\IRimage{example-image-a} \hfill  
\IRimage{example-image-b} \hfill  
\IRimage{example-image-c} \medskip\par
\rowlabel{Retrained with IR images}  
\IRimage{example-image-a} \hfill  
\IRimage{example-image-b} \hfill  
\IRimage{example-image-c} \bigskip\par
\hrulefill
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The devious trick doesn't work in this case. Here's an alternative version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\modulewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Inference on IR images using WaSR} 
\label{wasr_as_is_ir}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{2\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{2\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\modulewidth}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-1em-4\tabcolsep)/7}

\begin{tabular}{@{} c @{\quad} ccc @{}}
\toprule
\parbox{\modulewidth}{\raggedright Original IR images} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} \\
\addlinespace[2mm]
\parbox{\modulewidth}{\raggedright Direct inference} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} \\
\addlinespace[2mm]
\parbox{\modulewidth}{\raggedright Retrained with gray scale images} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} \\
\addlinespace[2mm]
\parbox{\modulewidth}{\raggedright Retrained with IR images} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} &
  \includegraphics[valign=c,width=2\modulewidth]{example-image} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all. However, I failed to mention one important thing here. I am creating a A0 size poster using 'baposter' class. I am creating a headerbox and the above table is inside this header box. It means I cannot use 'table' environment. Solution of 'js bibra' is coming closest to what I want except there is still an issue with spacing of text. I will share the new code and the output.

Comment: @shaileshn And where’s the problem? Use a minipage like in your example

Comment: please see update 2 above.